# DAX Minimum value grouped by sales order

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

Think a table:

[image: Table]

I cannot get my hands around the DAX-formula to get the CalcCol.

The rule is simple, if a random line in the order has a 0 then the CalcCol should be 0 - else it should be 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CalcCol =
CALCULATE(
    MIN( 'Table'[Value] )
    ,ALLEXCEPT( 'Table', 'Table'[Order#] )
)
```

Comment: I'm going to delete my answer and upvote greggyb's answer. My answer was more prone to other calculated columns hitting this error: http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-circular-dependencies/